# Equivalent of the WebForm_DoPostBack in ASP .NET in vba using MSXML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vba, excel

I have a webpage at URL = http://x/y/aspx/z.aspx.

The code in the html that I am targeting is like:-

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="z.aspx" id="Form1">
<INPUT id="ID1" class="Class1" value="xyz" name="ID1">
<INPUT onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ID2", "", true, "", "", false, false))' onkeypress=javascript:checkEnterPress(event); id="ID2" class="Class1" type="submit" value="Submit" name="ID2">
 </form>
```

Can someone explain what the page does on click of the Submit button?

How does the data, i.e., value of 1st input field sent to server?

- What I guessed is, the value gets appended as arguments(?ID1=xyz) to the url and sent back and the server extracts from it

I want to do the same using excel vba using MSXML
My code:

```
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

xhr.Open "POST", URL, False
xhr.send "ID1="& "xyz"
```

Now this leads me to the URL although it appears as if the data was not sent(posted).

In IE11, using F12 Developer Tools -> Network tab I was expecting to see some entries when I manually clicked Submit button but there was no fluctuations the Network tab remained blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not really the place for an explanation of exactly what happens when an HTML form is submitted, but your form is using the POST method so the data is transmitted in the *body* of the request, not as querystring parameters appended to the URL (which would be the case if GET was used).  If you want to see exactly what's going on during the submission then I'd recommend installing Fiddler and using that to examine the request/response.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks. I found it was some cookie issue. I had to use get first then submit the form using post. Fiddler is a very useful tool